# Typing $$$ + TAB => autoreplace with a custom text with Sublime Text

Tags: latex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible, with sublime Text 2, to replace `$$$` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> by a custom text, such as `\begin{myenvironment}\end{myenvironment}`?

**Is there a ready-to-use auto-completion feature (for .tex LaTeX) that I can customize to do this?**

Which config file should I edit to add this autocompletion setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a snippet in the menu *Tools > New snippet...* and save it in your User directory.

- For Windows users: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\tex.sublime-snippet`
- For Ubuntu users: `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/tex.sublime-snippet`:

The snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
\begin{myenvironment}$0\end{myenvironment}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>$$$</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

So that when you type `$$$` and hit Tab you will get `\begin{myenvironment}\end{myenvironment}`.

Edit: `$0` allows to choose where the cursor should be placed, after insertion.